# Why is Chrome so slow when loading many (≈130) png-images?

Tags: performance, google-chrome

Im making a page/application that presents a wide range of products. One view contains a lineup of about 130 products, eash represented by a png-image, the size varies from 33Kb to 150Kb.

The lineup can be scrolled horizontally whith the users scrollbar or custom controller, and when you hover each product I use som css-transistions to fade out all products except the one hovered, and to enlarge it.

It works perfectly smooth in Safari and decently Firefox, and in Chrome as long as I keep the image count-down. But the more images i try to add, both the scrolling and the transistions progressively gets slower until it's almost imposible to work with.

Is this some cache.problem in chrome? Is there any way around it?

I've tried to preload the images, but the problem isn't the loading time og the image, its the performance that seems to halt due to the sheer number of images.

Comment: I've found other instances where chrome is inexplicably slow, compared with other browsers.

Comment: Personally, I would find a site that blopped 130 products at me in one go annoying. But that's a design issue, and not a programming issue. :)

Comment: Hm, turns out the problem was that i updated the style property "position" to "absolute" by setting the style inline via javascript. When i did this by adding a class to the image instead, it worked better. Weird.

Comment: How much RAM does chrome use?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine all your little images in one big image, and load ONLY the big image, so you do only ONE HTTP request. For display you must set the offset (background-position property) of every image using css.

[Tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: The problem isn't the http-requests, when I removed the part where i changed inline stylesheets (position: absolute) and instead added a class that did the same, it worked fine. Also, it's not really an option to keep product-images in a sprite, since the maintanence would be a nightmare.

Comment: Maintaining is not a problem if you use an automatic script that merge all little images into bigger one. When you change an image just need rerun the script